# Efficiently write csv in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I test some function about write python list data to csv file, cost about 4~5 ms.
Is there more efficient way of save csv ?

```
    file_path = folder + guid + ".csv"
    out = open(file_path, 'a', newline='')
    csv_write = csv.writer(out, dialect='excel')
    for row_idx in range(0, 1000):
        ret_list = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 'hello pppp']
        csv_write.writerow(ret_list)
    out.close()
```

Comment: It's probably more efficient to first create the whole data frame with a list comprehension and then write it to file.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really without going through some significant hoops. Is 4 to 5 milliseconds, apparently including opening a file on disk, really too much?

(Note you're testing Python's performance to generate lists as much as the csv module.)

Answer (score 0):

Any I/O operation is expensive. You should minimize the number of them. Combine all rows into a list of rows and write the rows at once:

```
data = []
for row_idx in range(0, 1000):
    ret_list = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 'hello pppp']
    data.append(ret_list)
csv_write.writerows(data)
```